# Memory leak - debugger and memory analyzer disagreeing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, memory-management, memory-leaks

There is a memory leak in my android game - I've managed to narrow it down to a certain object, which has a list of objects to render on a texture. This object clears the list every time it draws though - so I can't work out how its managed to get thousands of elements in the list.

I checked in the debugger and it doesn't have all these thousands of elements - usually about 2-20 which is what I'd expect... The game definitely slows down progressively only if I have rendering to texturing on.

Here is a picture of Memory Analyzer showing 6,111 items:

[Memory Analyzer](http://i1135.photobucket.com/albums/m632/hanvyj/memoryleak.png)

Here is a picture of the debugger showing 2:

[Debugger](http://i1135.photobucket.com/albums/m632/hanvyj/memoryleak2.png)

Can anyone help me find out whats wrong?

Comment: You're sure the GC isn't just holding on to those for a while?

Comment: it might be that... I'll try to see if it gets cleared at any point

Comment: @Joe as my comment to teh1 was said, if those references were ready to be cleaned they wouldnt show up in default Eclipse MAT parsing.  If you follow the parse log you will see at some point it will remove unreachable objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can call System.gc(); to try to have the garbage collector work its magic. Give it a go.

Comment: That's not it assuming the OP ran the parse without -keep_unreachable_objects.  If he didn't those references wouldnt show up.  System.gc() will just clean up marked data to GC